# Out of memory error for a C++ executable

Tags: c++, opencv, out-of-memory, valgrind

I am trying to debug a weird Out Of Memory Exception. I have a C++ executable, that among other things, uses OpenCV and checks for Structural Similarity of two images.

Code:

```
Scalar getMSSIM( const Mat& i1, const Mat& i2)
{
const double C1 = 6.5025, C2 = 58.5225;
/***************************** INITS **********************************/
int d     = CV_32F;

Mat I1, I2;
i1.convertTo(I1, d);           // cannot calculate on one byte large values
i2.convertTo(I2, d);

Mat I2_2   = I2.mul(I2);        // I2^2
Mat I1_2   = I1.mul(I1);        // I1^2
Mat I1_I2  = I1.mul(I2);        // I1 * I2

/*************************** END INITS **********************************/

Mat mu1, mu2;   // PRELIMINARY COMPUTING
GaussianBlur(I1, mu1, Size(11, 11), 1.5);
GaussianBlur(I2, mu2, Size(11, 11), 1.5);

Mat mu1_2   =   mu1.mul(mu1);
Mat mu2_2   =   mu2.mul(mu2);
Mat mu1_mu2 =   mu1.mul(mu2);

Mat sigma1_2, sigma2_2, sigma12;

GaussianBlur(I1_2, sigma1_2, Size(11, 11), 1.5);
sigma1_2 -= mu1_2;

GaussianBlur(I2_2, sigma2_2, Size(11, 11), 1.5);
sigma2_2 -= mu2_2;

GaussianBlur(I1_I2, sigma12, Size(11, 11), 1.5);
sigma12 -= mu1_mu2;

///////////////////////////////// FORMULA ////////////////////////////////
Mat t1, t2, t3;

t1 = 2 * mu1_mu2 + C1;
t2 = 2 * sigma12 + C2;
t3 = t1.mul(t2);              // t3 = ((2*mu1_mu2 + C1).*(2*sigma12 + C2))

t1 = mu1_2 + mu2_2 + C1;
t2 = sigma1_2 + sigma2_2 + C2;
t1 = t1.mul(t2);               // t1 =((mu1_2 + mu2_2 + C1).*(sigma1_2 + sigma2_2 + C2))

Mat ssim_map;
divide(t3, t1, ssim_map);      // ssim_map =  t3./t1;

Scalar mssim = mean( ssim_map ); // mssim = average of ssim map
return mssim;
```

}

My matrices are huge - 3500 x 2500. I have a 32bit RHEL5 with 4GB RAM.
When I run this executable as such from the command line, it runs fine. 
But when I am calling this executable through apache-commons Executor() from a Java program, as an asynchronous process, it throws an Out Of Memory exception. Also I tried running this program under valgrind and it throws the same out of memory exception.

This function is called a fairly large number of times(around 2000 times). When run under valgrind and simultaneously monitor the memory usage with top, I see that after each execution of this function, the physical memory occupied kept increasing, ultimately leading to OutOfMemory exception. But when run normally, after each execution of this function, the memory consumption returns back to normal. This almost leads me to conclude that somehow, when run under valgrind, the function stack still persists without getting properly deallocated.

What is causing this behavior?

**UPDATE:** Valgrind version 3.9.0 does not throw OutOfMemory exception. Its only with Valgrind version 3.5.0

Comment: Does `Mat` is your own class? if yes, can you add it? (do you have a memory leak overthere?)

Comment: 32bit? Sounds like an address space exhaustion

Comment: Do you see top memory usage continuously increasing in both cases?

Comment: Mat is OpenCV Image Container.
@Spundun: Yes I see memory usage continuously increasing in both cases.

Comment: So it's simply a case of JVM putting stricter memory restrictions on it's subprocesses. But you still need to hunt down that memory leak.

Comment: I tried changing all the Mat objects in the function, to pointers and deleted them at the end of the function. When I do that, memory is de-allocated properly at the end of every function call.

Comment: I guess these huge Mat objects aren't freed properly after exit out of the function. If you try to create them at global scope and refer to them from your function, you will probably not get memory leaks either.

Comment: Is this process launched as an httpd child in apache?  Check the memory restrictions in httpd.conf http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/core.html#rlimitmem

Comment: You don't need to convert `cv::Mat` structures into pointers since `cv::Mat` takes care of the memory de-allocation automatically when it goes out of scope. Now that we have cleared that up, perhaps you can look into the comment of @fge. I agree with that and I think it might be an address space issue as well. HTH

Comment: No its not launched as a HTTP child.
@Ashalynd Creating at global scope does not throw error either. But why is it that the Mat objects aren't freed properly?

Comment: @scap3y How do I confirm that its an address space exhaustion? And if its indeed address space exhaustion, then why don't I get any error when using pointers and deleting them?

Comment: Maybe a step-by-step debugging would give you the answer. Regarding OpenCV's memory management, you should check out [this link](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/intro.html#automatic-memory-management).